# How to access formGroup inside component class

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Suppose I'm using `form` element inside `MyComponent` template. I'm using template driven approach to forms. So I use:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
```

I can then use form references inside the template like this:

```
<pre>Valid? {{f.form.controls.email?.valid}}</pre>
```

But what if I wanted to access the formGroup inside the component, how can I do that? I'm thinking that I can query it like this:

```
@ViewChild("f", {read: NgForm}) form
```

Is it the correct way to do so?

Comment: you want to access a form group of a child in a **parent component?** or in the **respective component** itself?

Comment: top level formGroup created by `ngForm`

Comment: can you please elaborate.

Comment: I've updated the question. I want to access `formGroup` inside `MyComponent` class

Comment: for what reason you are intending to access formGroup and its elements in your component class?

Comment: it's for educational purpose, just want to know how I can do this. I'm not working on any particular task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChild("f", {read: NgForm})` if you have multiple forms, or just `@ViewChild(NgForm)` if there is single form in template.

Comment: You should read `@ViewChild`/`@ViewChildren`/`@ContenChild`/`@ContentChildren` documentation. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Comment: thanks, I've read it before asking the question, so I was able to come up with `@ViewChild("f", {read: NgForm}) form` myself